# Payroll System - 'clock out' functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access, oledb

I am working on designing a payroll system using access database as back end.

Currently, I am facing problems implementing a 'clock out' functionality.

The 'clock in' button inserts the time in the database. However, when the 'clock out' button is clicked, it inserts the data into a new row. Is there any there any way to avoid this and to update the existing last row considering the Employee name. I have tried to approach this using different methods and so far I have not been able to solve it.

Is there any way to rectify this?

I think I would have to implement a loop somewhere to check emp name, clock in and locate null values in clock out field. Not sure though.

Please advise.

My code are as follows;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class timecards : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (Session["ID"] != null && Session["ID"].ToString() != "")
            {
                PanelUsersInfo.Visible = true;

            }
            else
            {
                PanelUsersInfo.Visible = false;
            }
            empLabel.Visible = false;
            mainPagebutton.Visible = false;
            logoutButton.Visible = false;
            if (Session["Title"] == null || Session["Names"] == null)
            {
                clockPanel.Visible = false;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                mainPagebutton.Visible = true;
                logoutButton.Visible = true;
                empLabel.Visible = true;
                empLabel.Text = "<b>Hi, " + Session["Names"].ToString() + "</b>";
                nameLabel.Text = Session["Names"].ToString();
                clockinLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
                Label1.Text = clockinLabel.Text;

            }
        }
    }




    protected void mainPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("employeeLoggedin.aspx");
    }
    protected void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
    protected void clockinButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        informLabel.Text = "Clocked in at " + Label1.Text + "";
        Label1.Visible = false;
        Label2.Visible = false;
        clockinButton.Enabled = false;
        clockoutButton.Enabled = true;

        string connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=" + Page.Server.MapPath("App_Data\\database.mdb");
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();


        cmd.Parameters.Add("Employee", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["Employee"].Value = nameLabel.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("Clockin", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["Clockin"].Value = clockinLabel.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [timecard] ([Employee], [Clockin]) VALUES (@Employee, @Clockin)";

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();




    }
    protected void clockoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clockoutLabel.Visible = true;
        clockoutLabel.Text = "You have now been clocked out.";
        informLabel.Visible = false;
        Label1.Visible = false;
        clockoutButton.Enabled = false;

        infoLabel.Visible = true;
        infoLabel.Text = "If you want to clock in again, please select timecard option from the main employee page.";


        string connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=" + Page.Server.MapPath("App_Data\\database.mdb");
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("Employee", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["Employee"].Value = this.nameLabel.Text;
        //String x = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Clockout", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["Clockout"].Value = this.clockinLabel.Text;


        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [timecard] SET [Employee]=@Employee, [Clockout]=@Clockout";




            conn.Open();
            int numberOfRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();



    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the users' interface?

Comment: you mean the database or just the UI for this code?

Comment: The ui.  I have a sense of what the answer might be, but I want to make sure I explain in the context of your situation.  It may be you need to change the way the user interacts with their time sheet to make this work reliably and correctly.

Comment: I can't help but notice the clockout's UPDATE statement doesn't have a WHERE clause.  `UPDATE [timecard] SET [Employee]=@Employee, [Clockout]=@Clockout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all who helped and provided suggestions to overcome the difficulty I was encountering.

Apparently, I found a solution. It's is better to store the values as string and then use WHERE clause to update it. For some reason, it will not directly take values from the textfields.

Answer (score 0):

If both buttons are INSERTing records then both buttons are running the same code. Check your `.aspx` page to see if both buttons happen to have the same `onClick=` attribute.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.
Both of the buttons have different onClick attributes.
onClick = "clockinButton_Click"
onClick = "clockoutButton_Click"